# Knockout : Async call not finished before ko.applyBindings(). Best, and easiest practice ?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i KNOW this question probably has been asked here before, but i just cannot seem to get any "best practice" which.. me as a newbie, can relate to in a easy understandable way...

**Knockout Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function viewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ClubWebServices.asmx/GetContacts",
            data: "{'abc':'" + 123 + "'}", // if ur method take parameters
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var contactData = data.d;
                console.log("Nr 1: " + contactData);
                self.contacts(contactData);

                console.table(self.contacts());
            },
            dataType: "json",
            failure: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

    console.table("Nr 2: " + self.contacts());

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

}
```

Result is that the console.log Nr 2 is called before Console.log nr 1..

So.. how do i solve this without creating a hierarky structure where i have to implement DataService layer's which uses OnSuccess and onFailure events ?

Comment: Try moving the `ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());` into the success callback

Comment: Yeah.. i tried that @Julian Soro, but... then the "function viewModel(){} wasn't executed... Know how ?

Comment: ... and... if i called it using viewModel(); the function was called twice... naturally because i returned new viewModel() in the success-call.. still.. the 2'nd was called before the first one... This stuff cracks my head :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some thoughts.

1. You're trying to create an instance of viewModel from within the function's declaration, this could lead to issues with the ko bindings.
2. Another note, is your references to `self` in the success callback may not be what you think it is. Using the debugger would give you clarity on that.

I would try rearranging some things like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var viewModel = function (contactData) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(contactData);
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ClubWebServices.asmx/GetContacts",
    data: "{'abc':'" + 123 + "'}", // if ur method take parameters
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
      var contactData = data.d;
      console.log("Nr 1: " + contactData);

      ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(contactData));
    },
    dataType: "json",
    failure: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });  

}
```

Changes: I close your `viewModel` declaration before the ajax request, and I'm passing in the `contactData` to the new `viewModel` constructor.

Also, creating a jsfiddle would greatly help with finding the cause of your error.

Comment: Thanks Julian :) Soon there now.. only getting errors when trying to foreach: through the data : 

Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return contacts }"
Message: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return DepartmentName }"
Message: DepartmentName is not defined

Comment: I made a fiddle.. Where the real data is presented as a json string, but i cannot get it to work (due to incompetancy :)) https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/28252/

Comment: @TerjeNygård Sorry for the delay, it's holiday here in the US. I've forked your jsfiddle, and noted some minor issues. You were really close. Here's a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/9u1czwLr/2/

Comment: Thanks a bunch Julian :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code has any problem.

- In ViewModel constructor,you bind the model to the DOM
- And after the service callback,you add data to the observableArray,then ko will update the binding DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your "Nr 2" table to be called after `self.contacts` is populated, subscribe:

```
var initialized = self.contacts.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    console.table("Nr 2: " + self.contacts()); // could use newValue instead
    initialized.dispose();
});
```

The `dispose` call keeps it from happening again on future updates. Or maybe you want it to, I don't know.

Oh, and as Julian Soro notes, don't call applyBindings inside the viewmodel creation function.